# javascript case-insensitive match for part of a string only

Tags: javascript, regex, case-insensitive

I have the following regex -

```
bannerHtml.match(/href\s*=\s*[\"']{clickurl}(.*)[\"']/);
```

which matches the following -
`href = "{clickurl}`

Now, I want the matching of `href` **only** to be case-insensitive, but not the entire string.
I checked adding `i` pattern modifier, but it seems to be used for the entire string always -

```
bannerHtml.match(/href\s*=\s*[\"']{clickurl}(.*)[\"']/i);
```

**Further details** 
I want all of the following to match -
`hREF = "{clickurl}`
`href = "{clickurl}`
`HREF = "{clickurl}`

But, capital case `clickurl` part should not match -
`href = "{CLICKURL}`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
/[hH][rR][eE][fF]\s*=\s*[\"']{clickurl}(.*)[\"']/
```

The part that changed is: `[hH][rR][eE][fF]`, which means:

Match `h` or `H`, followed by `r` or `R`, followed by `e` or `E`, and followed by `f` or `F`.

---

If you want to make it generic, you can create a helper function that will receive a text string like `abc` and will return `[aA][bB][cC]`. It should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: or you can just convert the string to lowercase and then test it against lowercase regexp :)

Answer (score 2):

You can't make it partially case-sensitive, but you can always be specific:

```
bannerHtml.match(/[hH][rR][eE][fF]\s*=\s*["']{clickurl}(.*)["']/);
```

The alternative to this is to discard false matches using a secondary regular expression.

As a note, it's not required to escape quote characters `"` as only the slash `/` is the delimiter.

Comment: Can you please give an example of the alternative? Any link or pointer at least? This method does not look very clean to me because we have to write for every character..

Comment: You can only ask so much from regular expressions, you know. Doing it for every letter might be annoying, but you're only dealing with four characters here. This is all the `/i` option does internally anyway. The option you have is to write a secondary expression to be sure `clickurl` is lower-case. This seems like a waste of time when this adjusted expression does the job.

Comment: @tadman or just create a helper function (if he will be using it with other regexes, not only with `href`) that will convert `xyz` to `[xX][yY][zZ]`..

Comment: For anything non-trivial, and four letters is most certainly trivial, typing out some brackets and extra characters isn't going to cause any serious injury or psychological harm. A helper will only complicate things.

Comment: Can we use (?i) (?-i) option.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I must say that's a very good question. I thought of 2 solutions to your problem:

1. make all `href` strings in lowercase:

   `bannerHtml.replace(/href/ig,"href")`
2. First of all I wrapped {clickurl} with parentheses for later use: `({clickurl})`.
   Then, I matched the whole case insensitive string to see if it matches the pattern. Lastly, I checked the `{clickurl}` string match which is stored in `result[1]` and see if its in the exact case.

   ```
   var re=/href\s*=\s*[\"']({clickurl})(.*)[\"']/i;

   var result = re.exec(bannerHtml);

   if(result && result[1]=="{clickurl}"){
       //Match!
   }
   ```

I know its not very regex solution but I that's the best I could think about. Good luck.